# Finding a missing index

Tags: sql

I've got a single table, with a autonumber id (called id) ranging from 1 - 159270 so select max(id) from table1 returns 159270, but I think one of the records has been deleted, is there a simple way to find out which id is missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brute Force:

```
SELECT * FROM table T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table T2 WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID - 1)
```

This should list rows JUST FOLLOWING the deleted ones.

Comment: Thank you very much, soted my problem, simple when you look at it, always forget how simple SQL

Comment: He did say that it would find list following the deleted ONES, it found what I was looking and proved that somebody/something had been deleting records, so happy

Answer (score 3):

Not working if more than one id is missing in a row... but fast:

```
select t1.id + 1 as missing_id
from mytable t1
left join mytable t2 on t1.id + 1= t2.id
where t2.id is null
```